# Amazon Product Advertising API does not Match Documentation (Java)?

Tags: java, api, amazon-advertising-api

I'm using the tutorial for Amazon Product Advertising API ([here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/index.html?YourDevelopmentEnvironment.html)) for Java.  I've generated the client code via the WSDL they provide.  When going through the code for an ItemLookup, I get to a section where I reference AWSECommerceServicePortType.itemLookup() by passing in an ItemLookup object, I get a compile error.  It seems that .itemLookup() is actually looking for quite a number of params - in other words, the method signature does not match the tutorial.  What am I missing?

Comment: and 5 years later again the documentation does not match the solution that needs to be implemented so you can make SOAP calls to the api, i had to read all the stack overflow questions and try millions different code combinations so i can make the solution to work

Maybe for the REST calls this is little bit easy

Answer (score 2):

### To generate the Product Advertising API Client Side Library stubs

**1. Go to the directory where you want to generate the stubs and create a "build" directory and a "src" directory.** All of the generated source code will go under the "src" folder.

**2. Create a custom binding to disable "Wrapper Style" code generation.**

```
<jaxws:bindings
wsdlLocation="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl"
xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
<jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
```

This step is necessary because the IDE does not support wrapper style generated code.

**3. Run the command:**

`wsimport -d ./build -s ./src  -p com.ECS.client.jax http://ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl -b jaxws-custom.xml .`

You can find the generated stubs in the path, com.ECS.client.jax .

***[Extract from the docs (page 10 from the pdf file)](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/Associates/2010-11-01/prod-adv-api-gsg-2010-11-01.pdf)***